# App Inventor App is too slow

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've developed a simple test app for Android with App Inventor. I've sent the .apk file to my smartphone, installed it and test it.
The app has only a screen view with 2 buttons: play and stop. Play starts the Player play method with a streaming server url string and stop button stops the Player.

The problem is that when I tap Play button, it remains in active state for a long time, until the Player starts to sound. When I tap Stop button, the Player stops immediately the Player but the button remains in active state for a long time like the Play button.

There are no other methods, screens or components.

At the moment the app is "unusable" because of it takes a very long time and I'm sure that the users should close the app.

Why? Which is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the phone spends a lot of time opening the file. Unfortunately the App Inventor is very simple and it doesn´t have a lot of other media tools. You can put a progress bar while the file is charging, but there aren´t many solutions...

Remind that the problem should be in the process of download the file instead of the phone. If you put the audio file in the app resources,  it will take you less time.

If you could make the app with Eclipse, you would have more options.

Hope it´s useful

Comment: Yes, it's useful but I'd like to understand because the button remains "pressed". I thought the problem is the streaming but it should takes time between the tap action and the streaming play. Is not correct? And why does the stop button remain "pressed" also if the streaming is stop immediately?

Comment: I don´t know, but you can try to load a downloaded file and see what happens. If you have the same problem, it might be a problem in your code, but if the stop button remains "pressed" too, it can be a common issue when you play a video from Internet. Try that in order to find where is the problem!!